# gradlew.bat not found in ubuntu

Tags: android, ubuntu, gradle, android-testing

I have used ubuntu OS.

In android studio terminal,I want to run gradle test in project.

When I ran command like : `gradlew.bat connectedInstrumentTest`

I got error like : `gradlew.bat : command not found`

Can anybody help me

Thanks in advance

Comment: No `.bat` on unix like OSes, see https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/gradle_wrapper.html

Comment: gradlew.bat file in project folder

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use

`./gradlew connectedInstrumentTest` Command instead of `gradlew.bat connectedInstrumentTest`